# Is it effective to decrease Gnome Shell's nice?

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, nice

I'm having some problems where GNOME Shell freezes because of a application (usually Firefox or discordapp).

Does decreasing its [nice](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nice.1.html) value to something around [-1](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/unix-linux-how-to-change-the-niceness-priority-of-a-process/) prevent freezing even when under high load from some application?

My main goal is raising the desktop responsiveness under load.

System info:

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
```

hardware: https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-VivoBook-15-X510UR/specifications/ + a 250 GB M.2 SSD

extensions:

```
ls  .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
alternate-tab@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
batterypercentageandtime@copong.gmail.com
caffeine@patapon.info
clipboard-indicator@tudmotu.com
cpufreq@konkor
dim-on-battery@nailfarmer.nailfarmer.com
drive-menu@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
extendedgestures@mpiannucci.github.com
extensions@abteil.org
extensions-sync@elhan.io
gsconnect@andyholmes.github.io
impatience@gfxmonk.net
night-light-slider.timur@linux.com
panel-osd@berend.de.schouwer.gmail.com
screenshotlocations.timur@linux.com
ShellTile@emasab.it
sound-output-device-chooser@kgshank.net
transparentosd@ipaq3870
user-theme@gnome-shell-extensions.gcampax.github.com
web_search_from_clipboard@awamper.gmail.com
wikipedia_search_provider@awamper.gmail.com
workspaces-to-dock@passingthru67.gmail.com
```

also may be of note that I have no swap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd add a swap file before trying an alteration of [nice](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/nice.1.html).

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq recomends having a swapfile or swap partition even if you have plenty of RAM, and the absence of swap space frequently causes freezes. Please generate a swap file, unless you use btrfs, in which case, a swap partition is recommended.

**1**g in the following line is the size of the swap file. You may change its size. **1GiB** is the file name; if you change it in one place, change it everywhere in the following commands.

```
sudo fallocate -l 1g /mnt/1GiB.swap && sudo chmod 600 /mnt/1GiB.swap 
sudo mkswap /mnt/1GiB.swap && sudo swapon /mnt/1GiB.swap
echo '/mnt/1GiB.swap swap swap defaults 0 0' | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
```

However, if this is ineffective at solving that issue, you can change nice values for apps permanently. Set the default nice value of a particular user or group in the */etc/security/limits.conf* file.

Comment: Thanks, I've added a swapfile of about 4Gib and it helped. but still sometimes a application "misbehaves" and freezes the whole desktop.

Comment: My main goal is to "detach" gnome-shell from the running applications, so it wont freeze when they do.